# Select an option when props change using react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am populating select options dynamically and I want select an option when ever `props.value` change comes. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const SelectElement = (props) => {
  const [httpError, seHttpError] = useState(null);
  const [getLoadedSelect, setSelect] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSelect = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(props.url + "?c=" + props.cat, {
        method: "GET",
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }

      const loadOptions = [];
      const responseData = await response.json();
      for (const key in responseData) {
        loadOptions.push({
          id: responseData[key].id,
          label: responseData[key].label,
          value: responseData[key].value,
        });
      }
      setSelect(loadOptions);
    };

    fetchSelect().catch((error) => {
      seHttpError(error.message);
    });
  }, [props.url, props.cat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.value)
    setSelectedOption(props.value);
  }, [props.value, props.random]);

  const selectHandler = (value) => {
    setSelectedOption(value);
    props.change(value);
  }

  return (
    <Select
    onChange={selectHandler}
    options={getLoadedSelect}
  />
  );
};

export default SelectElement;
```